# Javascript insert into with a variable table name

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

If my table name is a variable itself.  For example `var table1 = "beta1";` How should I adjust the statement below, where x is the variable?

```
        var sqlKIA = 'INSERT INTO X (command, extra) VALUES ('+commandvalue+','+extravalue+')';
        con.query(sqlKIA, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Node.js, you can use `??` as a placeholder for a table name or other identifier.

You should use `?` as a placeholder for a value or a list of values.

```
var table1 = 'beta1';
var params = [commandvalue, extravalue];
var sqlKIA = 'INSERT INTO ?? (command, extra) VALUES ?;
con.query(sqlKIA, [table1, params], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```

Please get out of the habit of using string concatenation to put variables into your SQL queries. That's an SQL injection vulnerability. Be part of the solution, not part of the problem.

Read more examples in the documentation for the `mysql` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values